# import csv file into database using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to import the csv file in database through php, but its not working properly. I dont know where I mistaken here is my code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $host = "localhost"; // Host name.
    $db_user = "root"; //mysql user
    $db_password = ""; //mysql pass
    $db = 'moodle'; // Database name.
    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $db_user, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());


    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, "."), (strlen($filename) - strrpos($filename, ".")));

    //we check,file must be have csv extention
    if ($ext == "csv") {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $sql = "INSERT into mdl_user(username,email) values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]')";
            mysql_query($sql);
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo "CSV File has been successfully Imported.";
    } else {
        echo "Error: Please Upload only CSV File";
    }
}
?>
```

here is the form code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="import_csv.php">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I didn't find where i mistaken

can anyone help me

thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you got any error ?

Comment: no its not showing any error too..can you please help me i am trying to do it from past 6 hours ..but i couldnt get the result

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Be sure to use prepared statements/parameter binding, so you won't have to worry about any quoting issues.

Comment: yeah okay i will use mysqli only if this function works i will use moodle functions actually..so all the insert code will change..i am just trying to use he function first

Comment: Are you getting any output, or just a blank screen?

Comment: i am getting just blank screen

Comment: actually i took the csv file from db itself..i just export my users table and i am trying to import it..

Comment: If it's a blank screen, then you're actually getting errors. You'll want to check your server error logs to find out the reason you're getting the error.

Comment: Add some debug statements at interesting places: `print_r($file)`, `print_r($sql)`. Also, activate php error reporting.

Comment: I didnt get  any errors in error log too..

Comment: @PaulH when i used print_r($file), print_r($sql) nothing is printing

Comment: @aynber i enbled error log to stll its not showing any errros

Comment: If `print_r()` is not showing anything, try removing code until it does.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple application to import CSV, that also support eastern languages using Laravel Framework, PHP Excel Lib, and Laravel Excel Lib,

If you would like to have a look, I can push to Github

Comment: Yes can you please push to github